# Order the sharepoint group-headings in a View

Tags: sharepoint, view, grouping

In Sharepoint (WSS 3.0) I have a list with a custom view that groups some items.

```
A
 item 1
 item 2
B
 item 3
 item 4
C
 item 5
 item 6
```

How can I specify a custom ordering of the group-headings? I would prefer to have something like C,A,B as example.
Is there a way to do so through CAML?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know the only way you would make thsi work is if you add some prefix to the group headings to allow ascending/descending sort to work.

For example

- (1) C
- (2) A
- (3) B

Comment: +1, tried to find a way but this will do, I have a display sequence # column to order items within a group